# How to define a dynamic global variable in code-igniter framework.

Tags: php, codeigniter, constants

How to define a dynamic global variable in code-igniter framework.

I am using Geo-Location tracking api, which tracks the country of the user based on user's IP address. 
I need to set the value of this global variable dynamically depending on the country code returned from the API.

what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: if you access config file through URL then you learned how to hacking website.

Comment: I am using geo-location api to track the location by ip and depending on the api response of the country code i need to change the country specific constants.

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the value of a constant in PHP. If you could it wouldn't be a constant. If would be good if you would better explain what needs to be achieved which might, in this case, be an explanation of how the api functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, You can store the value in session like this

```
$newdata = array(
               'country'  => 'Nepal',
           );

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

And again retrieve the session value like this

```
$country = $this->session->userdata('country');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at their website (see the [Config Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/config.html#environments)), it is written in great detail there.